# What's the best Wordpress page builder for creating custom HTML blocks and controls?

Tags: wordpress

I'm searching a most simple solution to create my own page builder system. I want to code my own blocks and then add to them some controls, only that what I choose.

So on firs fire goes ACF with ACF Extended. Works great until I didn't create more flexible fields. For example, I'm creating ROW (first flexible content) with a specified numbers of columns. Then, in each column I'm adding a BLOCK (second flexible content). Some of the blocks can contains other flexibles or repeaters. In ACF the problem is a lot of flexible and repeater fields. If is to much of them, then WP admin crash, data is saving, but sometimes only a partial.

So I'm searching other, lighter solution for that. I've tried I think every page builder like Elementor, WP Backery, Beaver. Problem is they are based on build-in elements and a lot of controllers. It's fine if someone want's to create site quickly, without coding. But I need a some kind of developer environment when I have control on each function of my HTML blocks.

So, is anyone knows what tool I could use for that?

Thaks!

Answer (score 0):

You did not name it in your list, so what about the Gutenberg Editor?
It's already in the core of wordpress, so the wordpress developers thought, this is the best block editor.

You can easily create your custom blocks and controls with ACF:
https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/blocks/

This may also help:
https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/blog/acf-5-8-introducing-acf-blocks-for-gutenberg/

With Gutenberg, you can be sure, this is not an editor which will be gone in a few years. It will stay in wordpress core and it is only in the beginning of becoming the best WYSIWYG Editor in the core of a cms.

Comment: I've been tried using Gutenberg across with ACF. For me Gutenberg is the least comfortable page builder.

Comment: ACF would be great if it could works more smoothly.

Comment: I think this is personal oppinion. As I said, Gutenberg is here so stay at wordpress core. No matter which page builder your are using, it will not be as optimized for wordpress as the Gutenberg editor is. If you want to have different oppions on which editor the users prefer in a personal matter, StackOverflow is not the place to ask such questions. You can edit your answer and describe which problems you are facing with using gutenberg or others editors. Maybe we can help you solve this problems.